# Django admin custom search filter or unicode handling

Tags: python, django

I put the UTF-8 encoded 'json' in models and then I add the search field to admin screen

`proj/myapp/models.py`

```
class MyJson(models.Model):
    my_json = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=20000)
```

`proj/myapp/admin.py`

```
class MyJsonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["my_json"]
```

then I try to search the word but in vain.

I guess it is because of text is stored as json with this Unicode Character.

`\u3054\u81ea\u7531\u306b\uff01\u3044`

Is there any way to solve this??

I think I should make custom search_fields callback though, I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: you can overrider ModelAdmin's [get_search_results](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results) method and process your custom logic.

Comment: Some rdbms _kind of_ "support" json (cf pgsql's JSON fields) and can do some (more or less restricted) custom queries on json content, but if you really want to have any barely efficient search on specific fields from your json blob, you'll have to use a proper relational model (=>parse your json to distinct fields or even distinct rows in related models etc). Also, a char field ("varchar" at the db level) is probably not the most efficient storage here, a text field would probably make more sense (or a proper json field if your rdbms support it of course).

Comment: Thank you I use jsonField for my model as you told, then now, Ibumped into the problem `Lookup 'icontains' doesn't work with JSONField`